# A value in SML which has a finite number of types n > 1

Tags: types, sml

So, the question is whether there exists, for any integer n, a value that has exactly n types.
For n=0, and n=1, the answer should be clear (zero, many), but what for n>1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question turns out to have a very simple answer: No.

The reason is that standard ML is based on a type system with inferred typing (particularly, the Hindley Milner type system). In this type-system, there is precisely one polytype for each value. You may want to consider a polytype which includes an unbounded number of types, e.g., type: 'a -> 'a includes in it very many types, e.g., int->int. In this case, there would be an infinite number of types to any HM polytype, e.g., a type that has parameters, and a finite number of types, precisely one, to any value whose type is not polytype.

In summary: Any corrrect value in ML has one polytype, and either one or infinitely mono-types.

Comment: You may want to differentiate between parametric polymorphism and ad-hoc polymorphism (aka overloading). For ad-hoc polymorphism the less simple answer is: Sometimes.

Comment: On the other hand, you may argue that for ad-hoc polymorphism (aka overloading), an expression like `op +`, while it overloads to three different types, is not the same value, since each one behaves differently (has different rules for rounding and/or overflows). In that case you're back to the answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

> For n=0, and n=1, the answer should be clear (zero, many).
>
> But what for n > 1?

*TL;DR:* For some n, yes, but not in general.

Let me understand if these clear answers are:

- n = 0: No, there are no values that belong to zero types. (If a value exists, it must have a type. Values don't exist in SML until their type is defined.)
- n = 1: Yes, there is a value that belongs to exactly one type. (There are infinitely many ways you can express a value that belongs to exactly one type: `datatype one = One`, `datatype two = One | Two`, `datatype three = One | Two | Three`, in which case any of these value constructors only belongs to one type at any one point.)

If this is not the correct interpretation of your question, could you perhaps clarify and elaborate the question and these clear answers? Continuing with the assumption that this interpretation is correct, here are some thoughts for n > 1:

For a value to have multiple types, the value must be polymorphic. I can think of two ways:

- For "[ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism)" (aka overloading): n = K: Some limited examples of overloaded, built-in operators that have multiple types (e.g. `+` having both type `int * int -> int` and `real * real -> real`, depending on what it is inferred as.) I honestly don't know exactly how many types have `+` overloaded for it, but I can see that it is at least 3:

  ```
  - 1 + 1;
  > val it = 2 : int
  - 1.0 + 1.0;
  > val it = 2.0 : real
  - 0w1 + 0w1;
  > val it = 0wx2 : word
  ```

  So for some arbitrary K ≥ 3: Yes, `op +` is a value that has exactly K types.

  Maybe there are multiple overloaded, built-in values with a different number of types, but since there are only finitely many overloaded, built-in operators, this can only be true for very few n > 1, and not for all n > 1 in general.

  You could argue that really these are three distinct `op +` values with the same name. They are implemented differently and they behave differently, so it would be reasonable to say that they're not the same value even though they share the same name. Under this strict interpretation, there is only parametric polymorphism left.
- For "[parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism)": The value `[]` has type `'a list`, but it also has type `int list`, `real list`, `bool list`, and so on. I don't know if you would say that it has infinitely many types, but I suppose you could say that. But even if you did say that, no value of type `'a something` would then have a finite number n > 1 of types. And neither would be the case for `('a, 'b) something`, and so on.

I can't think of other ways for a value to have more than one type within SML than these two kinds of polymorphism. An interesting follow-up question is if there exists meaningful ways to define values in any type system that have n types where n > 1, other than these two ways.

---

*If the question were "for **every** integer n ≥ 0, does a **type** exist that has exactly n **values**?" the answer would be "yes", since for n = 1 you have `datatype One = One`, for n = 2 you have `datatype Two = One | Two`, and so on. For n = 0 you could construct an abstract/opaque type with no exposed constructors. In Haskell this type is just `data Void` with no `= ...` part, but lacking this syntax in SML you could do something like:*

```
signature VOID = sig type t end
structure Void :> VOID = struct type t = unit end

fun whyNot (x : Void.t) = "I wonder how one might call this function."
```

*Even though `Void.t` is defined as `unit`, it is also made opaque, hiding the `()` value constructor:*

```
- whyNot ();
! Toplevel input:
! whyNot ();
!        ^^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   unit
! cannot have type
!   Void.t
```

*So the equivalence between `Void.t` and `unit` is not exposed, giving the type `Void.t` 0 values.*